# Exporting a dataset for each value of a variable

Tags: export, sas

I have a medical dataset with patients coming from several hospitals. What I'd like to get is an Excel file with each sheet being dedicating to a particular hospital. I have a variable stating from which one each patient comes so all I have to do is subsetting and export for each value of this variable.

I wrote this macro to do so for one particular value :

```
%macro exp_subset(table,var,value,out);

    DATA &table._&var._&value;
        SET &table;
        where &var = &value;
    run;
    proc export
        data=&table._&var._&value
        dbms=EXCEL
        LABEL
        OUTFILE="<path>\&out..xls"
        REPLACE;
        SHEET="&var._&value";
    run;
%mend;
```

And it works fine.
However, I'm having trouble appliying it on all values of the variable. After searching how to do it, I tried with `call execute()` :

```
%macro exp_subsets_all(table,var,out);

    proc sql noprint;
        create table dist_var as    /*this comes from another post of SO :P */
        select distinct &var
        from &table
        ;
    quit;

    data _null_;
    set dist_var
        (rename=(&var=values));
        call execute ("%exp_subset(&table,&var,"||trim(left(values))||",&out)");
    run;
%mend;
```

But it doesn't work and I don't quite understand the error.

[image]

Again, there is no such error when using `%exp_subset()`alone...
I'm very new with `call execute()` and I'm not sure what I can or cannot do. It seems to me I should be able to use it this way but am I wrong ?

Here is a table if you want to test (you'll have to specify a path in the first macro before):

```
DATA test;
input x y z;
cards;
1 2 3
4 2 6
7 8 9
7 11 8
;
run;

%exp_subset(test,x,7,table1);
%exp_subsets_all(test,y,table2);
```

Comment: I edited my code to applies the changes suggested by mjsqu, which prevent an unrelated error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are easier ways to accomplish what you want to achieve, but your code is failing because you've made some syntax errors in the `data _NULL_;` datastep:

**OLD**

```
data _null_;
set dist_var;
    rename=(&var="values");
    call execute ("%exp_subset(&table,&var,"||values||",&out)");
run;
```

**NEW**

```
data _null_;
set dist_var
    (rename=(&var=values));
    mac=%NRSTR("%exp_subset(&table,&var,"||trim(left(values))||",&out)");
    call execute(mac);
run;
```

**EDIT:** Added NRSTR to prevent %exp_subset resolving early.

**Changes**

- Rename changed to a dataset option, previously it was attempting to assign a new variable called 'rename' with the value (y="values"), which is a Boolean expression, evaluating to zero. You can see this by replacing `_NULL_` with a dataset name and taking a look at the resulting dataset.
- Noticed in the log that there were syntax errors relating to the formation of the dataset name when executing `exp_subset` with the `call execute` function, so added `trim(left(values))` to the call execute, which removes whitespace around the values of `values` and allows the dataset name to be formed correctly.

I ended up with datasets called:

- TEST_X_7
- TEST_Y_11
- TEST_Y_2
- TEST_Y_8

I also used `OPTIONS MPRINT;` which is a useful statement to run for debugging macros, as it'll show you the code executed in the log:

```
MPRINT(EXP_SUBSETS_ALL):   DATA test_y_8;
MPRINT(EXP_SUBSETS_ALL):   SET test;
MPRINT(EXP_SUBSETS_ALL):   where y = 8;
MPRINT(EXP_SUBSETS_ALL):   run;
MPRINT(EXP_SUBSETS_ALL):   DATA test_y_11;
MPRINT(EXP_SUBSETS_ALL):   SET test;
MPRINT(EXP_SUBSETS_ALL):   where y = 11;
MPRINT(EXP_SUBSETS_ALL):   run;
```

Remember to turn it off if using on macros that are likely to generate a lot of statements as you will fill your log:

`OPTIONS NOMPRINT;`

Comment: That's strange, I still get the same error. It seems to happend when I declare OUTFILE. My path is like OUTFILE="C:\blabla". As it works in the first macro, I didn't think this was the real issue but if your code works for you, it could be there after all couldn't it ? The log says "ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator."

Comment: MPRINT also showed that the macrovariables are not translated yet : I still get "&table" instead of "test",and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the EXPORT step when testing, I'll check now.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show that `ERROR 388-185` error and the point in the log that it appears please?

Comment: You're right, I should have done so since the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that error, sometimes when I have macro issues I just close SAS and then re-open it.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it seems there is a real error here... Thank you for your help anyway, your remarks were useful !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66118/discussion-between-mjsqu-and-vincent).

Answer (score 3):

I have a few suggestions for this.

First, whenever constructing a macro call, use single quotes.  This avoids the early resolution problem.

```
call execute('%exp_subset('...)
```

You can use double quotes after the very first bit, but the part that includes the `%` should include single quotes.  You can also add `%NRSTR` if you prefer, but single quotes are simpler.

---

Second, the `%exp_subsets_all` macro could be much simpler.

```
%macro exp_subsets_all(table,var,out);
    proc sql noprint;
       select distinct cats('%exp_subset(',"&table,&var,",&var.,",&out)")
        into :calllist separated by ' '
        from &table
        ;
    quit;

    &calllist.
%mend;
```

It's probably not different performance wise, but it's, again, simpler.  Only concern is that you need to be careful if you call this macro from a call execute - it must be included in `%nrstr` if so.

---

Third, the first macro should be one step:

```
%macro exp_subset(table,var,value,out);

    proc export
        data=&table.
        dbms=EXCEL
        LABEL
        OUTFILE="<path>\&out..xls"
        REPLACE;
        SHEET="&var._&value";
      where &var = &value;
    run;
%mend;
```

Comment: I have to admit that's way cleaner than my way ! Thanks :)

Comment: Cheers Joe, a succinct and elegant answer as usual!